# Hive too slow, how can I group files of small size?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I need to save a stream from kafka on hadoop and I used hive.
The streaming batch takes every 5 minutes the contents of kafka and saves it on a hive table, generating at each save a file small size (70KB) that slow down reading. you can configure hive in such a way that it compacts files to size 128MB each time a write occurs? Or do I need to perform manual HDFS commands?

I tried to set hive as below, but the problem did not resolve:

```
SET hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.size.per.task=128000000;
SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000000;
```

Comment: ORC format can be concatenated. using alter table...concatenate